# Validacion de fecha 2 meses posteriores Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tarde a todos tengo mi funcion que valida una fecha sin"/" ejemplo:`010218` seria(`01/02/2018`).
  Lo que básicamente necesito agregarle una validación mas la cual no me sale ,que seria que tire una alerta como las otras pero si la fecha ingresada es posterior a 2 meses a la fecha de hoy, por ejemplo hoy es `14/06/2018` (14062018) (me tendria que dejar hasta `14/04/2018` (140418) despues tira alerta. Me he quemado la cabeza y ya no me sale les agradeceria una mano

```
    function validarFecha2()
{
var date1Var = $("#date1").val();
var ano = (new Date).getFullYear();
var Mes12 = (new Date).getMonth();
var mes = date1Var.toString().substr(2,2);       
var dias = date1Var.toString().substr(0,2);
var anio = date1Var.toString().substr(4,2);
if(date1Var.length!==4 && date1Var.length!==6) {
swal("","Fecha debe contener 4 o 6 dígitos","warning"); 

}
if(date1Var.length==4) {
$("#date1").val(date1Var+'18');
anio='18'
}

if (mes<1 || mes>12 || dias<1 ||dias>31)  {
swal("","El Mes debe ser entre 01 y 12","warning");  


      }
anio='20'+anio;

if (anio>2018)
{

swal("","El año no puede ser mayor a 2018","warning");  

}
var fecha_formateada=[dias,mes,anio].join('-'); 
var fecha_iso = [anio,mes,dias].join('-');
var date=new Date(fecha_iso);

//si es mayor a fecha de hoy en dia valido
if(date.getTime()>Date.now()) {

swal("","La fecha no puede ser mayor a hoy","warning");  

}

}
```

Comment: Por que haces la fecha manualmente? no puedes hacer uso de DatePicker

Comment: Hola , para dar facilidad , rapidez y no usar el mouse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo una idea por aquí cambia las variables como mejor te convenga:

```
var f = new Date
var mes = f.getMonth()
mes = parseInt(mes)
var mesIntroducido = 5//mes introducido
if(parseInt(mesIntroducido) > mes+2){//el parseInt es por si te devuelve un String
    swal("","El mes insertado no es válido","warning");  
}
```

Comment: Gracias hermano me diste una gran mano

Comment: De nada bro... para eso estamos =)